# How to combine two halves from two bytes to get a single byte

Tags: byte, bit, byte-shifting

Let us say that `byte1 = 00001111`, and `byte2 = 11110000`. How would I take the second half of `byte1`, then take the first half of `byte2` and combine them to get one byte of value `11111111`. I have done some research, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around bitmasks and shifting.

Answer (score 2):

*If* it's guaranteed that the "spare" bits are all zeroes, you can just `OR` together the two bytes, since `A or 0 == A`  (see below)

If that's not guaranteed, you need `(byte1 AND 0x0f) OR (byte2 AND 0xf0)`.

The `AND` operations set the unwanted bits to zero (since `A AND 0 == 0`) and then the `OR` operation combines the bytes, as above.

```
    ABCDXXXX              XXXXEFGH
AND 11110000 (0xf0)   AND 00001111 (0x0f)
    --------              --------
  = ABCD0000            = 0000EFGH
```

and then

```
    ABCD0000
 OR 0000EFGH 
    --------
  = ABCDEFGH
```

No bit shifts are required because the bits you want to keep are already in the correct bit positions.

Comment: Where did you get the hex 0x0f?

Comment: @Hobbs2000  That's just the hex for `0b00001111`